# Java was started but returned exit code = -1

Tags: java, eclipse, rad

When I started Eclipse this popup message appears , i tried to re-locate JVM and increase XX:maxPremSize
but there is no use , what does mean exit code = -1 ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means the JVM didn't start properly.

If you changed `N > 1` things in these JVM settings (start-up parameters), you should go back to the original values of all the start-up parameters, and then start changing them one by one. This way you'll find out which change from those you did actually caused the problem.

Comment: so .. the problem not from allocated memory ..!!

Comment: As said I don't know what you changed exactly. Go back to the original values, and start changing them one by one.